# How to select for rows in a dataframe that have a time within 30 minutes of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge, difftime

I have 2 datasets that looks like the following (with about 600 total entries for both)
Dataframe1

| name | A_time | measurement_A |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 6/10/22 7:22 | 3.4 |
| A | 6/10/22 16:15 | 4.4 |
| A | 6/11/22 6:15 | 5.5 |
| A | 6/11/22 15:44 | 6.6 |
| B | 5/20/22 6:30 | 7.6 |
| B | 5/20/22 13:21 | 1.2 |
| B | 5/21/22 8:43 | 2.4 |
| B | 5/21/22 14:35 | 4.4 |

Dataframe2

| name | B_time | measurement_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 6/10/22 7:24 | 50 |
| A | 6/10/22 16:55 | 50.1 |
| A | 6/11/22 6:13 | 52 |
| A | 6/11/22 15:21 | 61 |
| B | 5/20/22 6:30 | 54 |
| B | 5/20/22 13:22 | 53 |
| B | 5/21/22 8:00 | 54.6 |
| B | 5/21/22 14:12 | 76.1 |

I want to combine these two dataframes by name and date, selecting for rows only where Dataframe1 and Dataframe2 are within 30 minutes of each other.

I'm hoping to get something like this:
**Dataframe3**

| name | A_time | measurement_A | measurement_B |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 6/10/22 7:22 | 3.4 | 50 |
| A | 6/11/22 6:15 | 5.5 | 52 |
| A | 6/11/22 15:44 | 6.6 | 61 |
| B | 5/20/22 6:30 | 7.6 | 54 |
| B | 5/20/22 13:21 | 1.2 | 53 |
| B | 5/21/22 14:35 | 4.4 | 76.1 |

The code I am using:

```
library(dplyr)

dataframe3 <- dataframe1 %>%
  inner_join(dataframe2, by = "name") %>%
  filter(abs(A_time - B_time) <= as.difftime(30, units = "mins"))
```

But I am getting an error because the names in dataframe1 correlated to multiple rows in dataframe2. How can I get the Dataframe3 that I want?

Answer (score 3):

`merge`, then `subset`, conveniently in a `list`.

```
Reduce(\(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), list(d1, d2)) |>
  subset(abs(as.integer(A_time - B_time)/60L) <= 30L, -B_time)
#    name              A_time measurement_A measurement_B
# 7     A 2022-06-11 06:15:00           5.5          52.0
# 12    A 2022-06-11 15:44:00           6.6          61.0
# 13    A 2022-06-10 07:22:00           3.4          50.0
# 18    B 2022-05-20 06:30:00           7.6          54.0
# 21    B 2022-05-20 13:21:00           1.2          53.0
# 32    B 2022-05-21 14:35:00           4.4          76.1
```

---

*Data (assorted rows!):*

```
d1 <- structure(list(name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), A_time = c("6/10/22 16:15", "6/11/22 6:15", "6/11/22 15:44", 
"6/10/22 7:22", "5/20/22 6:30", "5/20/22 13:21", "5/21/22 8:43", 
"5/21/22 14:35"), measurement_A = c(4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 3.4, 7.6, 
1.2, 2.4, 4.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

d2 <- structure(list(name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), B_time = c("6/10/22 7:24", "6/10/22 16:55", "6/11/22 6:13", 
"6/11/22 15:21", "5/20/22 13:22", "5/20/22 6:30", "5/21/22 8:00", 
"5/21/22 14:12"), measurement_B = c(50, 50.1, 52, 61, 53, 54, 
54.6, 76.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

d1$A_time <- strptime(d1$A_time, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
d2$B_time <- strptime(d2$B_time, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')
```

Answer (score 2):

If your system can handle an almost cross join, lubridate for dates

```
library(lubridate)

df1$A_time <- as_datetime(df1$A_time, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")
df2$B_time <- as_datetime(df2$B_time, format="%m/%d/%y %H:%M")

df3 <- merge(df1, df2, by="name")
df3[abs(difftime(df3$A_time, df3$B_time, units="mins")) <= 30, ]   
#    name              A_time measurement_A              B_time measurement_B
# 1     A 2022-06-10 07:22:00           3.4 2022-06-10 07:24:00          50.0
# 11    A 2022-06-11 06:15:00           5.5 2022-06-11 06:13:00          52.0
# 16    A 2022-06-11 15:44:00           6.6 2022-06-11 15:21:00          61.0
# 17    B 2022-05-20 06:30:00           7.6 2022-05-20 06:30:00          54.0
# 22    B 2022-05-20 13:21:00           1.2 2022-05-20 13:22:00          53.0
# 32    B 2022-05-21 14:35:00           4.4 2022-05-21 14:12:00          76.1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set `relationship = "many-to-many"` in `inner_join()` to silence the warning.

```r
df1 %>%
  mutate(A_time = strptime(A_time, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')) %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>% mutate(B_time = strptime(B_time, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')),
             by = "name", relationship = "many-to-many") %>%
  filter(abs(difftime(A_time, B_time, units = "mins")) <= 30) %>%
  select(-B_time)
```

Another `dplyr` solution with ***overlap joins***:

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(A_time = strptime(A_time, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M'),
         A_lower = A_time - 30*60,
         A_upper = A_time + 30*60) %>%
  inner_join(df2 %>% mutate(B_time = strptime(B_time, '%m/%d/%y %H:%M')),
             by = join_by(name, between(y$B_time, x$A_lower, x$A_upper))) %>%
  select(-c(A_lower, A_upper, B_time))

# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   name  A_time              measurement_A measurement_B
#   <chr> <dttm>                      <dbl>         <dbl>
# 1 A     2022-06-10 07:22:00           3.4          50  
# 2 A     2022-06-11 06:15:00           5.5          52  
# 3 A     2022-06-11 15:44:00           6.6          61  
# 4 B     2022-05-20 06:30:00           7.6          54  
# 5 B     2022-05-20 13:21:00           1.2          53  
# 6 B     2022-05-21 14:35:00           4.4          76.1
```

---

###### Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), A_time = c("6/10/22 7:22", "6/10/22 16:15", "6/11/22 6:15", 
"6/11/22 15:44", "5/20/22 6:30", "5/20/22 13:21", "5/21/22 8:43", 
"5/21/22 14:35"), measurement_A = c(3.4, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.6, 
1.2, 2.4, 4.4)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

df2 <- structure(list(name = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"
), B_time = c("6/10/22 7:24", "6/10/22 16:55", "6/11/22 6:13", 
"6/11/22 15:21", "5/20/22 6:30", "5/20/22 13:22", "5/21/22 8:00", 
"5/21/22 14:12"), measurement_B = c(50, 50.1, 52, 61, 54, 53, 
54.6, 76.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge` with `all = TRUE` + `subset`

```
subset(
    merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE),
    abs(difftime(
        strptime(A_time, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"),
        strptime(B_time, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"),
        units = "mins"
    )) <= 30,
    select = -B_time
)
```

which gives

```
   name        A_time measurement_A measurement_B
7     A  6/11/22 6:15           5.5          52.0
12    A 6/11/22 15:44           6.6          61.0
13    A  6/10/22 7:22           3.4          50.0
18    B  5/20/22 6:30           7.6          54.0
21    B 5/20/22 13:21           1.2          53.0
32    B 5/21/22 14:35           4.4          76.1
```